# Wrap column headers in a latex table exported by pandas.df.to_latex()

Tags: pandas, latex

**Problem:** Tables output by Pandas.DataFrame.to_latex() do not wrap long column headers.    The line_width= parameter has been removed as of Pandas 0.24.

**Discussion:**

I'm exporting many tables with the df.to_latex() command, for inclusion in a master document.  Many of the tables have wordy column headers, mostly owing to the need to include parenthesized units.

The end result is a set of absurdly sparse tables that often won't fit on the page.

Here's a sample of the too-sparse generated Tex:

```
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrrr}
\toprule
{} & Odometer (km/y) & Fuel (L/y) & Elec (kWh/y) & Economy (L/100km) & GHG (kg CO2e) & GHG (g/km) \\
Type          &                 &            &              &                   &               &            \\
\midrule
Type 1         & 70753.62 & 9721.06 & 0.00 & 13.74 & 21386.33 & 302.26 \\
Type RRR     & 56167.39 & 5285.40 & 1627.60 & 9.41 & 11642.54 & 207.28 \\
Type X        & 195756.35 & 42957.04 & 0.00 & 21.94 & 94505.48 & 482.77 \\
Type Huh        & 187384.66 & 18118.07 & 73.07 & 9.67 & 39860.40 & 212.72 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

**Questions:**

- Is there an alternate method of specifying wrapping in my generated .tex?
- Alternately, is there latex magic that will let my master latex document `\input` these tables and specify a wrap width?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem relies on the way columns are declared. When specifying 'r', you say 'do a column wide enough for the larger cell and right aligned'.

What you need to do is use the `column_format` argument to give a width of the column with p{width}, in which case columns items will be formatted as a paragraph of the given width with line breaking as required.

E.g., the Pandas command:

```
df.to_latex(column_format='lp{1.8cm}p{1.8cm}p{1.8cm}p{1.8cm}p{1.8cm}p{1.8cm}')
```

Should result in an output .tex file that looks more-or-less like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lp{1.8cm}p{1.8cm}p{1.8cm}p{1.8cm}p{1.8cm}p{1.8cm}}
\hline
  {} & Odometer (km/y) & Fuel (L/y) & Elec (kWh/y) & Economy (L/100km) & GHG (kg CO2e) & GHG (g/km) \\
  Type          &                 &            &              &                   &               &            \\
  \hline
  Type 1         & 70753.62 & 9721.06 & 0.00 & 13.74 & 21386.33 & 302.26 \\
  Type RRR     & 56167.39 & 5285.40 & 1627.60 & 9.41 & 11642.54 & 207.28 \\
  Type X        & 195756.35 & 42957.04 & 0.00 & 21.94 & 94505.48 & 482.77 \\
  Type Huh        & 187384.66 & 18118.07 & 73.07 & 9.67 & 39860.40 & 212.72 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\bigskip

If you want to control line breaking, just add a $\backslash${newline} where you want.

\begin{tabular}{lp{1.8cm}p{1.8cm}p{1.8cm}p{1.8cm}p{1.8cm}p{1.8cm}}
\hline
  {} & Odometer\newline (km/y) & Fuel \newline (L/y) & Elec\newline (kWh/y) & Economy\newline (L/100km) & GHG\newline (kg CO2e) & GHG\newline (g/km) \\
  Type          &                 &            &              &                   &               &            \\
  \hline
  Type 1         & 70753.62 & 9721.06 & 0.00 & 13.74 & 21386.33 & 302.26 \\
  Type RRR     & 56167.39 & 5285.40 & 1627.60 & 9.41 & 11642.54 & 207.28 \\
  Type X        & 195756.35 & 42957.04 & 0.00 & 21.94 & 94505.48 & 482.77 \\
  Type Huh        & 187384.66 & 18118.07 & 73.07 & 9.67 & 39860.40 & 212.72 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\bigskip

You can also consider adding an extra row for the units.

\begin{tabular}{lp{1.8cm}p{1.8cm}p{1.8cm}p{1.8cm}p{1.8cm}p{1.8cm}}
\hline
  {} & Odometer & Fuel  & Elec & Economy & GHG & GHG \\
  Type &  (km/y) &  (L/y) & (kWh/y) & (L/100km) &  (kg CO2e) &  (g/km) \\
  \hline
  Type 1         & 70753.62 & 9721.06 & 0.00 & 13.74 & 21386.33 & 302.26 \\
  Type RRR     & 56167.39 & 5285.40 & 1627.60 & 9.41 & 11642.54 & 207.28 \\
  Type X        & 195756.35 & 42957.04 & 0.00 & 21.94 & 94505.48 & 482.77 \\
  Type Huh        & 187384.66 & 18118.07 & 73.07 & 9.67 & 39860.40 & 212.72 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The .tex is generated by df.to_latex().  I do not have control over the column declarations.

Comment: You can  use the last solution (put units in a separate line), with any column descriptor, including 'r'. The appearance will be better than you original table and it will solve your immediate problem. But columns will not be of identical width, as it is for p{width}.

Comment: It turns out that there is a `column_format` argument on `pd.to_latex()`.  I've submitted an edit to your solution to make it directly answer my question.  I'll accept once the edit is approved.